# Run C# function in another form

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have 2 forms in c# named MainPage and Roles.

MainPage is the main form and Roles is a usercontrol form. I'm displaying "Roles" inside in "MainPage" using PanelSlider so both are loaded and showed at the same time.

I am trying to send some text from Roles to MainPage but I can't manage to do this; I'm also trying to run a function in Roles from MainPage.

MainPage code:

```
public MainPage(string action, string user)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    PanelSlider.Controls.Find("Roles", false)[0].BringToFront();
    if (action == "accepted")
    {
         SideNavButtonContainer.Visible = true;
         siteuser.Text = user;
         siteuser.Visible = true;
    }
}
        
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // When this button is clicked I want to run 
    // doChange("started"); in Roles
}
```

Roles code:

```
public partial class Roles : UserControl
{
    public Roles()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         MainPage frm = new MainPage("accepted", mname.Text);
         // Here I tried changing the text in MainPage 
         // but it does not change anything.    
    }

    private void doChange(string what) 
    { 
        //This is the function im trying to run from MainPage
        label1.Text = "Function has been run";
    }
}
```

How can I send text from Roles to MainPage and then run `doChange("started")` from MainPage to Roles?

I tried sending the text using

```
MainPage frm = new MainPage("accepted", mname.Text);
```

But nothing changes at MainPage.

Comment: Feedback: if you can run an English spell-checker on your posts here, it is appreciated. Remember that your questions and answers have long-term educational value for other readers.

Answer (score 1):

To access a method in another class you need to have that method visibility set to *public*, but that's not enough. You need also a reference to the object instance of the Roles class currently used in you main page.
So you could write something like this

First make the method public in the Roles class

```
public void doChange(string what) { 
   label1.Text = "Function has been run";
}
```

then change your MainPage code to

```
private Roles usrRoles;
public MainPage(string action, string user)
{
      InitializeComponent();
      // Get the reference to the current instance of the usercontrol of type Roles 
      usrRoles = PanelSlider.Controls.Find("Roles", false)[0] as Roles;

      // We should really test for null here, but for keeping the example simple..
      usrRoles.BringToFront();
      if (action == "accepted")
         ...
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Now you can call the method defined by the Roles on the current usercontrol instance 
    usrRoles.doChange("started")
}
```

Note that I use a global class variable named *usrRoles*, you can remove it but then in the button1_Click code you need to get the reference again with Panel.FindFirst

Likewise, if you want to send something to a MainPage class instance you need a reference of the current MainPage instance that is hosting the UserControl. This could be retrieved from the *this.Parent* property of the user control, and then call the public method on that MainPage instance

Instead the code *MainPage frm = new MainPage("accepted", mname.Text);* creates a new instance of MainPage, and this new instance is never shown, while the current existing one is not affected at all.

So add a public method to MainPage

```
public void RunCommand(string command, string parameter)
{
     if(command == "accepted")
        .....
}
```

and call it from the UserControl button1 click event

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // this cast is necessary because Parent is of type object 
   // and object has no RunCommand method. Cast will fail if 
   // Parent is not an instance of MainPage
   var mainP = this.Parent as MainPage;
   if(mainP != null)
       mainP.RunCommand("accepted", mname.Text);
}
```

So, apart from giving an answer to your question, I wish also to include a link to an article that explains the difference between [Class, Objects and Instances](https://www.codementor.io/@stevedonovan/class-vs-object-vs-instance-14i2s2lu6r). It is of uttermost importance to understand correctly these concepts and how they are applied in the programming language of your choice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, when trying to use
usrRoles = PanelSlider.Controls.Find("Roles", false)[0];

i get this error:
CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control' to 'MyProject.UserControls.Roles'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Added _as Roles_ to the mentioned line